# Event confirmation e-mail is showing empty values for the mandatory profile fields

Tags: civievent, civimail

I'm using the Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line) under the workflow messages in the e-mail templates.

My event is using a custom Profile for the form fields.

**The confirmation page in de event form flow is correctly showing ALL entered values.**

**The confirmation e-mail however, is showing empty values for all fields that were made mandatory** in the profile. Screenshot added:

[image]

The code from the e-mail template (from: civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1 => Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line) ) I could work with is:

{if $customPre}
{foreach from=$customPre item=customPr key=i}
    {$customPre_grouptitle.$i}
   {foreach from=$customPr item=customValue key=customName}
   {if ( $trackingFields and ! in_array( $customName, $trackingFields ) ) or ! $trackingFields}
     
         {$customName}
         {$customValue}
     
   {/if}
   {/foreach}
{/foreach}
{/if}

This isn't telling me much, though.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Mandatory was not the trigger of this.
Fields of type: "Money" don't get printed in the e-mails.

Another nice one!